# Android Variable Optimisation

Tags: android, optimization

I want to optimize my Android application, but i don't know what is better?

First option:

```
public void function()
{
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    ...
}
```

Second option:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

public void function{
   ...
}
```

Which option use less resource? Global variables or local? (My program call this function every second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the second option is better. `findViewById()` can be fairly expensive if your view hierarchy is complex.  It is better to call it once and store the results than to call it repeatedly.

Comment: Is any better altenative for `findViewById()`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second option uses e.g. member variables, it won't even work. You need to call `setContentView()` e.g. in `onCreate()` before calling `findViewById()` and member variable initialization is performed before your `onCreate()` runs.

So the first one is better because it works while the other doesn't.

Other than that, at this level this smells of unnecessary micro-optimization. If you have performance issues, they are probably elsewhere.

Related: If you want to optimize `findViewById()` calls e.g. in an adapter where the same views are recycled over and over again, google for "android viewholder".

Comment: Ok I know for that but what is better to use first or second option?